# Graph Without Rounded End Caps

Tags: java, android, graph, android-graphview

I did managed to draw the graph that i wanted but some how I'm getting rounded end caps at the end of the graph lines.

I wrote my code using the GraphView lib for a series of data using this :

```
GraphViewSeries line1Series = new GraphViewSeries("LINE ONE", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(Color.BLUE, 100), exampleSeries2);
```

How can I change the end cap from rounded to a straight end cap like this one:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7545176/4953542/227d9380-6682-11e4-88fd-4ad1f4a5ac14.png

Comment: Someone is out there for help ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably to clone the project from github and alter the `onDraw()` method in `GraphView.java` (line 154 as of now) from:

```
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
```

to

```
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
```

Comment: No im not drawing data points... The rounded cap is caused by the Thickness that is set to 100 as you can see from the code line that i posted...it seems like it's some bug when you set the line thickness to be higher.

Comment: @WoW Apologies - I see what you mean. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did imported the project to eclipse changed the line 154 but how do i add this as a jar file into my current project to check if it's working ?

Comment: @WoW [This page](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html) explains how to make your new project into a library project (check the part starting _You can also convert an existing application project into a library_). Further down that page it tells you how to reference that library project in your current project.

Comment: I added the project as a library to my project but im getting errors like it doesnt recognize : import com.jjoe64.graphview.BarGraphView;

Comment: Finally it's working without rounded caps ! Thanks alot for the help :)